# What does "(My)?[It]*dos+" means in app.get("/get(My)?[It]*dos+",

Tags: node.js, url, express, get, routes

Hey guys can you help me with this problem? Can't seems to find an answer on the internet.

```
app.get("/get(My)?[It]*dos+", function (req, res) { ..... });
```

Can anyone tell me what

```
 "/get(My)?[It]*dos+"
```

means? This is a weird way to define url route.

Comment: Not really, given so little context.

Comment: Didn't you accept my answer?  Was sure you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I paste your route into the [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/?_ga=1.52333865.1412927197.1486077930) it tells me that it will convert it to the following regular expression:

/^/get(?:(My))?[It]*dos+(?:/(?=$))?$/i

I am not going to try to analyze that off the top of my head, but you can go to [Regexr](http://regexr.com/), paste in the above expression into the expression area.  Click on explain in the Tools section and it will tell you what each part means.  The i at the end means ignore case.